# I can't load a Helm chart into IBM Cloud Private

Tags: kubernetes-helm, ibm-cloud-private

I'm trying to load a Helm chart into IBM Cloud Private. When I run the `bx pr load-ppa-archive --archive` command or the `bx pr load-helm-chart --archive` command, I get an error that says that it can't load my Helm chart:

`FAILED
Post https://mycluster.icp:8443/helm-repo/import: Service Unavailable`

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to load the Helm chart from a node in the IBM Cloud Private cluster, this error can be caused by your `http_proxy` or `HTTP_PROXY` settings. You can try two things:
1. Install the CLI on a computer that's not in the cluster and upload the chart from there.
2. Add `mycluster` and `mycluster.icp` to the `NO_PROXY` variable on the cluster node and try again.